# How to automatically add multiple pods for a single target in ionic project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, podfile

I want to generate the following Podfile on running ***ionic cordova add platform ios***

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
target 'Sunorbit' do
    project 'Sunorbit.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'
end
```

but currently  the 5th line `pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'` is not getting generated
So I have to manually add it and then run 3 seperate commands

`pod deintegrate`
`pod install`
`pod update`

which I don't want to do.
So what should I do to automatically add `pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.1'` for a single target `target 'Sunorbit'` in an ionic project